# Getting force close when i add view to other view when a thread is running

Tags: android

I am getting the below error

```
12-30 05:40:40.484: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-10 exiting due to uncaught exception
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2629)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:545)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7657)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7657)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7657)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7657)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7657)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1749)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1708)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1688)
12-30 05:40:40.494: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(413):     at com.wwwww.shout.presentationLayer.Shout$1.run(Shout.java:137)
```

and my code is

```
myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Shout.this,"","Loading...",true);

         new Thread() 
         {
         public void run()
         {
             String xml;



                 xml="<spGetUserMessages><SearchLocation></SearchLocation></spGetUserMessages>";
                 messages =parse.GetGetUserMessages(dataparsing.ILGetUserMessages(xml));
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearlayoutMessage)).addView(iiii);


      }

    }.start();
```

at the time of adding views to the layout i am getting the above error.what is the wrong in this.Please give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Handlers as in [this example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/threads-and-handlers-android-developer.html)(`handleMessage` runs on UI thread, so there you can modify views) or for more sophisticated things, use [AsyncTask](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/82805.aspx) (`onPostExecute` runs also in UI thread)

That's how your code should look like using Handler:

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //in case you passed data to message (see below) here you can retrieve it
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearlayoutMessage)).addView(iiii);
    }
};

private myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Shout.this,"","Loading...",true);

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        String xml;
        xml="<spGetUserMessages><SearchLocation></SearchLocation></spGetUserMessages>";
        messages = parse.GetGetUserMessages(dataparsing.ILGetUserMessages(xml));
        Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage();
        //here you can add data to the message using msg.obj, msg.what...
        //refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html for details
        myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
   }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the UI thread can modify views.

Use [Activity.runOnUIThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)